# Advantages of using co over async/await functions and compiling with babel

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs, co

Co bills itself as a ["stepping stone towards ES7 async/await"](https://github.com/tj/co#co-v4), but I'm not really sure why I should use it over just writing async functions and using babel to compile. Are there any advantages and disadvantages to these approaches or is it just a question of preference?

Comment: async/await is not part of ES7.

Comment: *"I'm not really sure why I should use it over just writing async functions"* you don't have to. As it says it's a stepping stone *towards* async/await. If you can use async functions with Babel, then do that.

Answer (score 2):

Async/Await is more like writing sync code and is where es is going. It's just syntax to make it simpler/more intuitive to write async code.

### Evolution of Async Syntax:

callbacks --> promises --> async/await

[This article](https://nulogy.com/who-we-are/company-blog/articles/from-promises-api-to-async-await/) shows how the syntax can make certain situations much more concise and arguably more intuitive.

Comment: Doesn't really address the question IMO.

Comment: Well, my answer as to why he might use it is because that's where ES is going, but your above point about async/await not being included in ES7 might make my point moot.

Comment: Yeah I much prefer writing async/await functions, I guess I'm just confused as to why co even exists/is so popular. Felt like there was something I was missing.

Comment: @JoeBushell: not everybody wants to transpile their code.

Comment: @FelixKling fair enough, I guess that's my question answered. Thanks for the help, I think I spend too much time worrying if I'm doing things 'right'.